# Power Query - Meeting Requests. Why so slow?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, exchange-server

I am trying to run a PQ that will fetch the information on my calendar for a load of bookings that are made via MS Bookings over a year (around 6000 bookings per year).
It's insanely slow!!
I tried a few things to potentially speed it up (eg: Table.Buffer, and also attempted to expand the body on one table and expand the properties on another and merge using ID as the key field, but it's still slow. And when i say slow, I mean I gave up on the refresh after an hour!

Below is the first part of the code I'm using..

```
let
Source = Exchange.Contents("xxxxxuniversity6@xxxxxuniversity.onmicrosoft.com"),
#"Meeting Requests" = Source{[Name="Meeting Requests"]}[Data],
#"Filtered Rows1" = Table.Buffer(Table.SelectRows(#"Meeting Requests", each [Start] > #datetime(2022, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0))),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each Text.StartsWith([Subject], "Credibility")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"DisplayCc", "RequiredAttendees", "OptionalAttendees", "IsAllDayEvent", "IsCancelled", "LegacyFreeBusyStatus", "IsReminderSet", "ReminderMinutesBeforeStart", "Importance", "Categories", "HasAttachments", "Attachments", "Preview", "Body"}),
#"Expanded Attributes" = Table.Buffer(Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Attributes", {"MeetingRequestType", "AppointmentSequenceNumber", "DateTimeReceived"}, {"MeetingRequestType", "AppointmentSequenceNumber", "DateTimeReceived"})),
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Expanded Attributes", {"Id"}, #"Calendar (3)", {"Id"}, "Calendar (3)", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Calendar (3)" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Calendar (3)", {"Interview DateTime", "Student Name (Booking)", "Email (Booking)", "Service Booked", "Student Number", "Student Number.2", "Interview Is-Was"}, {"Interview DateTime", "Student Name (Booking)", "Email (Booking)", "Service Booked", "Student Number", "Student Number.2", "Interview Is-Was"}) in
#"Expanded Calendar (3)
```

I also tried using the simple email address as source rather than the----onmicrosoft.com, but that kicks up errors if you try to expand the Body or the Attributes.

Anyone any suggestions?

Comment: Is just running `Source = Exchange.Contents("xxxxxuniversity6@xxxxxuniversity.onmicrosoft.com"),` fast?

Comment: No that bit is quite rapid, it's only when I start expanding it grinds almost to a halt.